# choosing y/n while linux boots up (SUSEstudio Testdrive)

Tags: linux, opensuse, susestudio

so i used SUSEstudio to create a small distro and while i use testdrive the kernel boots up and shows the following screen:
[image]

so my question is (a very silly one,sorry) how do i press yes or no,like which key,i possibly tried all combinations and even googled it,but of no avail,

Comment: If you already tried SPACE and TAB I'd assume your testdrive is misconfigured. Maybe you'd like to test the custom distro DVD image with qemu or VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the system at question, but usually you either select with arrows and press Enter OR type `Y` and `N`, may be with Shift.